# Determining original authors of parts of texts from revision histories

Tags: php, text, revision-history

I have revision histories of text and I would need to determine which parts were written by which users. Is there a php code that I could use? Or a good algorithm?

What I came up with was not good enough: split the text to sentences and call the first user who wrote a particular sentence as the author of this. This is quite efficient, not precise enough for my purposes. Also, I have been thinking of using a diff algorithm, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Take Revision 3 for example: diff with Revision 2 tells what parts were written by User 3, but how to determine which parts of the remaining text were from Revision 1?

Comment: Maybe you could use git as a backend for storing your texts and get the information you are looking for with "git blame".

Comment: `Take Revision 3` for example...?

Comment: @Coulton Sorry that the wording was unclear. This was meant to be an example. Let's call the revisions: Revision 1, Revision 2, Revision 3, etc, written by Users 1, 2, .... I am not sure how to use diff to determine which parts of Revision 3 were written by Users 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: You'd have to store each version in a database against the user id

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer thanks for a pointer. I would prefer to do this with php only, since I'm not sure I can install git to the server, but it is good to know how this function is called in git.

Comment: @Coulton could you be more specific? Of course, I save the user id's with the revisions, otherwise I could not do much.

Comment: @TomH Sorry you didn't provide that detail.  Maybe you need to provide some example revisions and ask how you can display a diff of that data with the data structure and everything.  Without it, the question isn't specific enough :(